# Decryption not working on a saved image but works on the pixel manipulated matrix of the image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

A very beginner in `OpenCV`
I am trying to implement text steganography: Trying to hide a text message in an image.
What I do is, I hide each of the characters from the text message by modifying the pixels in the image. For each of the characters I take the binary representation of the character and replace the last bit of a pixel with the LSB of the character, and gain last bit of another pixel with the 2nd bit of the character, and so on .... for the whole message. 
After this encryption of the text into the image I store it on the disk using `cv::imwrite`.

This image is again read in by another routine and decrypts it doing the reverse opeartions used for encrypting.

But, the problem is decryption is not working if i read in the image(encrypted image) whihc is stored using `cv::imwrite`.
But, it works if I pass-on the encrypted matrix (`cv::Mat`) object to the decryption routine rather than reading a image again.

Seems, something is getting changed when i store the encrypted matrix into an image.
Not sure what is going on behind the scenes. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you loose the information when saving.

According to the documentation of `imwrite` function ( [imwrite() documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite) ) the function chooses the format of the image based on the extension of the filename you are giving. Could it be that you are using a lossy file format such as JPEG (`*.jpg`)? instead try using a `.png` which uses a lossless compression to save the data.

**EDIT:**
You can use different approach for steganography specially designed for jpeg images: http://www.sav.sk/journals/uploads/0317153109jo-mo.pdf

Comment: Didn't know about it. I tried it out with png, I am able to decrypt the message now completely. Thanks a zillion times!!. But, is there no workaround for jpeg images ? Because I think while writing in jpeg it decompresses the compressed jpeg.

Comment: jpeg is lossy format by definition, so I'm afraid there is no workaround this....